# How to add content above TabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I need to add a `ContentView` above a `TabbedPage`, so in Android it will be just above tabs and on iOS it will be above the content of each page. Can it be done with custom renderers for `TabbedPage` or any other way? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: What type of content are you looking to add?

Comment: A StackLayout full width, 60 height, with some content. Basically a toolbar created in forms.

Comment: There _may_ be a way to do that on Android, but far easier would be to just have your toolbar above the content of each page on both platforms. This is because the tab bar is placed automatically by Forms in the place where Android users most expect it to be.

Comment: We ended up getting rid of `TabbedPage` in favor of `CarouselView`. Looks like it's indeed not worth the effort to try to put something above the tabs.